# Adding active class for "Home" link JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bet this is as easy as 123 but, I have a Navigation with JS which adds dynamically a class "active" to a "li a" element which is currently active. How to change JS code so that when page loads Home link (first link which shows when user enters page) it has ".active link" on it.?
Here is my example!

http://jsfiddle.net/SZ63C/

**JS:**

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Home link should be with "active" class from the beginning...

Please take a look at jsfiddle and help me if possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can add class active to your home link in your html, you don't need javascript to handle this.

```
  <li><a href="#Home" class="scroll active">Home</a></li>
                                 //-^^^^^^--here
```

well if incase you want then you can use eq..

```
$('.scroll:eq(0)').addClass('active');
```

inside your document.ready function

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ63C/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('li a:eq(0)').addClass("active");// here add active class on load
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/SZ63C/1/)**

reference **[eq-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.scroll').first().addClass('active');
```

- Get the first link using [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method.
- Then add the `active` class to the link.

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ63C/3/)

**A simple performance tip:**

Use the code below to remove class from only the links already having the class. There is no need to unnecessarily remove class from all the links.

```
$('a.active').removeClass('active');
```

This will look for all the links having the `active` class and then remove that class, reducing the scope of having to check all the links and increasing efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to dynamically add the active class on any page, try something like this.

```
$("li a").each(function(){
   if( $(this).attr('href').indexOf( window.location.pathname ) !== -1 ){
       $(this).addClass('active');
       return false; // case found, break each loop;
   }
});
```

Otherwise if you wish to just add it to the Home link only, and never another try:

```
$("li a").first().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document ready function and write your code into it.
Take the help from below link:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/